# Why Jsp pages are not directly converted to bytecode?

Tags: jsp, servlets, bytecode-manipulation

Jsp pages are first converted to *.java files and then this source file is compiled and executed by the container. why can't we use some byte code engineering libraries to make the class files directly?

Comment: I'm sure you could if you wanted to spend a lot of time building that, but why do you even want to?

Comment: Is there any advantage current method of conversion is having than the method I suggested ?

Comment: 1) Don't reinvent the wheel. 2) Significantly less work (an order of magnitude). 3) Independence from 3rd party libraries. 4) Portability. 5) Maintainability. 6) Reliability. 7) Testability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Sun engineers chose this approach because of its simplicity. It is trivial to generate servlet java source file from jsp. And then they just use standard compiler. They do not care about low level compiler stuff, they just reuse existing components. Classical KISS - keep it simple, stupid.